# Questions about representation and distribution of primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

I came across the following examples and have a few questions about them.

> $1$. There are at least $3\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ primes in the range $n$ through $n!, \ (n \ge 4)$.

In the proof below I omit the computational details and the case where $n$ is odd for brevity:

> Proof: The statement is true for $4 \le n \le 9$, so assume $n \ge 10.$ Let $n = 2k, \ (k \ge 5).$ Then $n! > 2^{3k}n$. By Bertrand’s conjecture  there are at least $3k =3(n/2) = 3\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ primes in the range $n$ through $2^{3k}n$, that is, between $n$ and $n!$.

---

> $2$. How many primes are there such that the digits in their decimal values alternate between $0$s and
> $1$s, beginning with and ending in $1$?

In the solution below I drop some computational details:

> Solution: Suppose $N$ is a prime of the desired form and it contains $n$ ones. Then $N = 10^{2n - 2} + 10^{2n - 4} + \ldots + 10^2 + 1 = \frac{(10^n - 1)(10^n + 1)}{99}$. Now $n = 2 \implies N = 101.$ If $n > 2$, then $(10^n - 1),(10^n + 1) > 99$ and so $N$ is composite meaning $101$  is the only
> prime with the desired properties.

---

My questions:

$1$. In the first problem, how do they compute the number of primes between $n$ and $2^{3k}n$ to be $3k?$ If I understand Bertrand's conjecture correctly, there's a prime between $2$ and $2^{3k + 1}$, another prime between $3$ and $3(2^{3k})$, yet another one between $4$ and $4(2^{3k})$ and so on. How do they get $3k$ such primes? If this is not Bertrand's conjecture, how do they apply the actual conjecture to get $3k$ primes?

$2.$ This question is more of an idle curiosity. Is there a method for deducing a general formula from a pattern (as described in the problem $2$ above) like $N = 10^{2n - 2} + 10^{2n - 4} + \ldots + 10^2 + 1$ ? It seems especially complicated given that $N$ also has to be prime. Is it just a trial and error process?

$3$. In the second problem, how do we know $N$ is composite for $n > 2$?

Comment: Bertrand's postulate (not just a conjecture, but proven!) states that there is a prime strictly between $n$ and $2n$ for every $n>1$. Hence we have a prime between $n$ and $2n$ , between $2n$ and $4n$ , between $4n$ and $8n$ and so on. Hence, $3k$ primes between $n$ and $2^{3k}\cdot n$ are sure whenever we have $n>1$

Comment: we know $N$ is composite for $n>2,$ because, for $n$ even, $N=\dfrac{10^n-1}{99}(10^n+1)$ is a non-trivial factorization, and, for $n$ odd, $N=\dfrac{10^n-1}9\dfrac{10^n+1}{11}$ is

Comment: If we can find so-called "algebraic factors", we can sometimes prove that a number must be composite. For example, $2^p-1$ can only be prime if $p$ is prime, since otherwise there is $a\mid p$ with $1<a<p$ and $2^a-1$ is a proper factor (unless $p=1$, which is however an obvious case). A similar approach was used in the solution.

Comment: Hint for question $2$: Multiply $1010101\cdots 10101$ with $99$ and look at the decimal pattern of the result. Warning : It is not always so easy to find a formula.